# I want to revert to a backed up copy of my App

Tags: git

I have researched this topic, but am afraid I have too little experience with Git and may be causing more problems by trying out different things, so I am posting to find out the best way to revert to a previous state of my App.

I committed the changes and deleted the previous branches, but not before I backed up the app locally on an external drive.

Everything was working fine (function-wise), as evidenced by my deployment to Heroku, which is still working, prior to my most recent changes.

I failed to create a branch for the new changes, something I will never do again, and I was working off the master. False confidence...

So, since everything went so horribly wrong, I decided to copy over the backed up App and start new... but that didn't work.

I think it could be a simple matter of reverting to uncommitted changes on the master, but I am a little frozen with fear that I may make a misstep.

Can you help???

I am working on rails 3.2, ruby 1.9.3, git 1.7.4.4

Update

---

I have used git reset --hard HEAD and now terminal tells me 
    HEAD is now at 820f417 micro.

Problems I'm having are:

I don't know how this may or may not change files I have edited inside textmate and saved to the hard drive.

When I open the app in the browser, I am getting the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in StaticPagesController#home

Could not find table 'users'
```

Trace:
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:46:in `user_from_remember_token'
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:16:in`current_user'
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:9:in `signed_in?'
    app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:4:in`home'

Comment: What have you committed? If the working version was committed to git, all you need is to fetch that version. Forget about the backup in that case. That's what you have version control for.

Comment: Agreed re. hard drive. Copying your repository to an external source will simply confuse matters—as it has already done. If you are worried about "back-ups", create a Github repository and push your local changes to it. This has the added benefit of giving you a nice UI for your seeing your commit tree on Github.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverting commits is covered in [**the Git Book**](http://book.git-scm.com/):

- [Undoing in Git - Reset, Checkout and Revert](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html)

If you haven't *committed* the changes, you can't revert to them. Unless I misunderstood you and you wish to revert un-commit changes back to the last committed version, in which case this is easy.

Here's an example:

Here's a file after four revisions. Only the first three have been committed.

```
> cat file
This is revision 4
```

Get the status:

```
> git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   file
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Revert to the last committed version:

```
> git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at e0d512a Revision 3
```

Look at the file:

```
> cat file
This is revision 3
```

Revert the last commit:

```
> git revert HEAD
Finished one revert.
[master 92a575c] Revert "Revision 3"
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

Look at the file:

```
> cat file
This is revision 2
```

View the revision history:

```
> git log
commit 92a575c481c69fc1dd809ba02a63009141f95b96
Date:   Fri Mar 2 17:13:36 2012 +1100

    Revert "Revision 3"

    This reverts commit e0d512acebbfb3891888dc59074f7d1f0748bba6.

commit e0d512acebbfb3891888dc59074f7d1f0748bba6
Date:   Fri Mar 2 17:11:25 2012 +1100

    Revision 3

commit efc6d5af434c56991dabee43f36bc6e7ff284da7
Date:   Fri Mar 2 17:11:01 2012 +1100

    Revision 2

commit 8b73c59bb517df2589dcd0285a6d19045882ad8e
Date:   Fri Mar 2 17:10:20 2012 +1100

    Revision 1
>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am reading that right now and have used: git rest --hard HEAD, which has taken me back to my last committed branch, I think... What I'm not clear on is how does git change the state of the files on my hard drive to revert to the previous state? I will keep reading, but that would help a lot.

Comment: Git keeps a record of all committed modifications to your files in the hidden .git/ directory for your repository. The `git reset` command simply makes changes to the working tree and/or index by looking up the modifications necessary for each file to contain the correct contents to equate what was in that commit.

Comment: I've added an example, I hope this helps.

Comment: That's good info. My problem persists, however. See my second update... Ugh.

Comment: The example I presented shows *exactly* what Git does with the files on your HDD. I'm afraid I can't help you with the Ruby errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the SHA hash of the commit to which you would like to restore your working tree, you can use `git checkout <commit> --` to get the specified commit on your current branch.

If you wish to see the difference in the content of your files, you can use the `git diff` command. If you want to compare your working tree to what is on the HEAD of your branch (last commit), use `git diff HEAD`. If you want to see the difference in specific files, list those files at the end of the diff command. You could use git diff to compare with external files, however you should probably focus on determining if your repository still has the commit containing the repository status you need before looking at external back-ups.

Comment: Does the SHA appear in here:Brian$git commit -a -m "micro"
[master 820f417] micro
 8 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

Comment: Yes, 820f417 is the first part of the commit SHA, which is sufficient to refer to that commit (you don't need the full thing).

Comment: Hmm... when I input this: git checkout <commit> 820f417, I get this:
-bash: commit: No such file or directory

Comment: Right. What you want to do is `git checkout 820f416 --` when you are on the master branch of your repo.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to throw away my recent changes on a committed file, say A.cpp.

I use `git checkout -- A.cpp`

Comment: Thanks. No luck with anything.